# When will Eclipse support Java 9 natively?

Tags: eclipse, java-9

I know that there is a plug-in *[Java 9 Support for Oxygen](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-oxygen)* but does anyone know when will Eclipse support Java 9 natively? I looked on project website and blog ([planet eclipse](http://planeteclipse.org/planet/)) but can't find any information.

Comment: isn't this more of a question towards their support team, rather than SO?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Support for **JDK 9** and **JUnit 5** will come with [**Eclipse Oxygen.1a, October 11, 2017**](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?eid=Mm51M2lkbzB1aDVqMGt0OThxNDhta2gxazQgZ2NoczdubTRudnBtODM3NDY5ZGRqOXRqbGtAZw&ctz=America/New_York&sf=true&output=xml#eventpage_6).

See also the [announcement on the Eclipse [cross-project-issues-dev] mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg14739.html).

***Update***: The above mentioned version is released (see [my video that shows the built-in Java 9 and JUnit 5  support of the Eclipse Java IDE Oxygen.1a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8)).

If you update Eclipse Oxygen with *Java 9 BETA Support for Oxygen*, **uninstall *Java 9 BETA* manually** (see [Eclipse bug 526065](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526065)).