# MacOS: Eclipse will not start when Java 9 is the default

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-9

I have a MacBook Pro, last year i've installed Eclipse just to try it and suddenly i've uninstalled it. Now i need it for an exam at University but i can't install it anymore..at the start it says "An error has occurred. See the log file /Users/andry_900/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.log." but the directory /Users/andry_900/eclipse-workspace/ is empty, there's no log.
Please help me..how can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: *An error has occurred. See the log file* - Did you see the log?

Comment: Well, start by reading the log that it tells you to read, which will give you some details. What you've posted here is absolutely useless. See [ask].

Comment: @AndreaBellia Likely `.metadata` is a hidden folder, you'll have to disable hiding hidden files and folders to see it. Or just `cd` through the command line.

Comment: Have you tried the eclipse support forums?

Comment: Maybe is Java 9 the problem?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46369792/2670892 You have to modify the eclipse.ini to run with Java 9

Comment: Thanks, problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running with Java 9.  Downgrade to Java 8 for Eclipse.

Comment: The changes in Java 9 are small but sum up to - to my understanding  - all non-trivial applications having some kind of trouble.  This is unprecedented for Java but is apparently the price we need to pay for modularization so we can bundle small JRE's with our applications.  It appears that we all need to let the tool "vendors" have some time to make things work in the new world.

Comment: You [don't need to downgrade to Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/6505250). [Eclipse Oxygen.1a which will be released on October 11, 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360931/6505250) will run also with Java 9 without this modifications.

Comment: @howlger Naturally future versions of Eclipse will work.  But if you cannot afford to wait more than two weeks, downgrading Java is a simple solution.

Comment: [Adding the line `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` to `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/6505250) seems to me to be the simpler and quicker solution. It is also the [solution that is recommended by Eclipse itself](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9).

Comment: @howlger Given the experience level indicated by the wording of the question I disagree.    This is not about being absolutely technical correct in every detail, but to help a person with his/her immediate problem in a way they are comfortable with.  You have enough reputation to know that you should write your own excellent answer instead of this commentary "I know I know better than you"-stuff.  This also allows the voting mechanism to let people _show_ what was the most useful to them when they came to this question.

Comment: Based on your answer that has been accepted, it is clear that the question is a duplicate. I don't have enough Stack Overflow reputation to mark the question as a duplicate. Can you do that?

Comment: It is non-trivial for an inexperienced programmer to apply the "just patch eclipse.ini file" fix under MacOS.    That difference alone is enough to warrant a separate answer.